# Plot 1D Lanczos Interpolation

Tags: python, image-processing, signal-processing, interpolation, lanczos

Imagine we have the following points:

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
y = [2, 3, 5.5, 6.5, 5, 4, 5, 7.5, 8, 7]
```

[image]

Now we want to interpolate every point using lanczos interpolation like:

```
lanczos_interpolation = lanczos_interpolation(x, y)
xs = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
interpolated_xs = lanczos_interpolation(xs)
```

How can I implement the `lanczos_interpolation`? I have already seen `interpolate.interp1d` but lanczos is not available...

I want something that if plotted would look like (the provided example is with bilinear interpolation):
[image]

Comment: The wanted result is a line! :)

Comment: The number of points can be like 100, I just want to interpolate the points provided as x,y

Comment: Sorry, fixed it! The plots had the corret number of x points (starting in 1)

Comment: Lanczos interpolation is not defined (AFAIK) for inputs at arbitrary points. You need input data samples at regular intervals. You happen to have an example with x values at integer coordinates, but it is not clear if this is always the case?

Answer (score 2):

This is the OpenCV Lanczos interpolation.

EDIT: Open CV interpolates for images, so actually it extrapolates data, because the starting points are pixels, and an image with more pixels, since it has smaller pixels, it has pixels outside the original range:

For example, on this image, initially there are 2 pixels, but if OpenCV is asked to interpolate to 20 smaller pixels, there would be 5 extra pixels on each side of the image. That is why the interpolation doesn't match.
[image]

Unfortunately, this means that this method cannot interpolate between points at arbitrary coordinates.
The original points have to have a constant separation.

This code does a dirty approximation, because there is no guarantee that the pixels will match exactly:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2

x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
y = [2, 3, 5.5, 6.5, 5, 4, 5, 7.5, 8, 7]

img = np.array([y])
parts = 100
xs = np.linspace(1, 10, parts)
resized = cv2.resize(img, (int(parts*(1+1/len(y))), 1),
                     interpolation=cv2.INTER_LANCZOS4)[0]

plt.scatter(x, y)
plt.plot(xs, resized[int(parts/(2*len(y))):int(parts/(2*len(y)))+parts])
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Should't it be alined with the points?

Comment: I think the problem might be that we are not fitting the points to the interpolation? For example using `scipy.interpolate.interp1d` we first need to pass x and y before interpolating with xs

Comment: Why lanczos? Why not a cubic or quadratic, so you can use scipy?

Comment: I already made the code for 1D bicubic (cubic), 1D bilinear (linear) and 1D nearest with scipy. I need to make lanczos as well as a mens to compare them. Do you know any other solution?

Comment: Lanczos is a convolution with a mexican hat function. So you may generate the mexican hat, and use a convolution. Ask the people on wavelets, most probably they already have it under another name.

Comment: there is no "bug" in OpenCV, at least not with Lanczos. this is the expected result. the interpolation is not required to pass through the points. -- _maybe_ the issue could be the coordinate systems of OpenCV, how `src` is mapped to `dst` given a desired size.

Comment: Is there something useful in this link https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/interpolate.html#module-scipy.interpolate?

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I understand what you said, but why do bilinear and bicubic interpolations pass through the points but lanczos doesn't? I want to fill/interpolate in the middle of the points

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz is there any way this can be useful to build an interpolation that passes through the points? https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.sinc.html

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz It is not interpolation if it doesn’t pass through the input data points. The problem is that OpenCV resize does weird things with the coordinate system.

Comment: sure, interpolation, by definition, must have that property. -- *if* lanczos is merely a convolution of some kind... a kernel centered on a certain data point and applied to the signal is *not required* to equal that data point. -- given that the answer was edited to show that the values _do_ line up, I guess *lanczos* does make that guarantee. -- I never use cv.resize unless I don't particularly care... when I need precision, I use warpAffine and a custom matrix. sadly that no longer allows INTER_AREA...